# Why do I get name 'Attr' is not defined when trying to do a DynamoDB scan?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to write a logic to perform dynamodb scan operation with begins_with filterexpression but getting some error.

I've the following code written:

```py
    table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('Employee')
    response = table.scan(
        ProjectionExpression='#k,#s',
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#k' : 'EmpId', # partition key
            '#s' : 'EmpDepartment'  # sort key
        },
        FilterExpression=Attr('EmpId').begins_with('123')
    )
```

Getting the error -

> [ERROR] NameError: name 'Attr' is not defined
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 25, in lambda_handler
>     FilterExpression=Attr('EmpId').begins_with('123')

What is the correct way of using `begins_with` in dynamodb scan filterexpression?

Comment: Have you imported `Attr`? If not, try `from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr` - does that work?

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks @ErmiyaEskandary

Answer (score 2):

Import `Attr` to be able to use it.

```py
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr
...
```